# WPF 4.0 Application load error in some environments

Tags: wpf, load

I have 4 environments:

1. Win 7 64 bit
2. Win 2003 32 bit
3. Win XP SP3 32 bit
4. Win 2003 64 bit

In the first 2, my app loads and runs successfully. In the latter 2, I get the following error (shortened):

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The method or operation is not implemented.
---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType bamlType, Int16 typeId)
...
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
...
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at DBSophic.Qure.WorkloadAnalyzer.UI.App.InitializeComponent()
in e:\Qure\Dev\BuildSystem\Sources\Trunk\DBSophic.Qure.WorkloadAnalyzer.UI\App.xaml:line 1
at DBSophic.Qure.WorkloadAnalyzer.UI.AppMain.Main()
in e:\Qure\Dev\BuildSystem\Sources\Trunk\DBSophic.Qure.WorkloadAnalyzer.UI\AppMain.cs:line 21
```

What might cause it?

Answer (score 8):

The missing DLL will be one referenced by a namespace in your XAML.

Comment: This was essentially the problem I had. I wrote up a whole Q&A about how to solve it because my context was a little different from this question, and it seems to me the `NotImplementedException` hides many potential root causes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74460799/1688738.

Comment: PS I'd love to know how you knew this answer, although maybe you can't remember from eleven years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Try loading your application in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if all dependent modules exist on each computer.  As a guess I'd question if DBSophic is installed with the correct version (or at all), and of course that the latest .NET 4 framework is installed.

Answer (score 2):

It was a missing dll.