# AutoCAD Custom Extended WPF UpDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autocad, wpf-extended-toolkit

based on Extended WPF Toolkit I want to create my own `CommonNumericUpDown<Station>` for AutoCAD Stations along Alignments. This works pretty fine in a StandAlone-WPF-App. If I netload it in AutoCAD from anywhere on disk I get a XamlParseException "The method or operation is not implemented.", but placing my dll in AutoCAD-install-directory it also works fine. Also creating my own `CommonNumericUpDown<Double>` works pretty fine. The error also only appears as soon as on setting one of UpDownBase's properties. Where is AutoCAD cheating me?

Here is my Code. To simplify as much as possible I extended `UpDownBase<T>`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

namespace My.AutoCAD.UITest
{
    class UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown : UpDownBase<double>
    {
        protected override double ConvertTextToValue(string text)
        {
            return double.Parse(text);
        }

        protected override string ConvertValueToText()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }

        protected override void OnDecrement()
        {
            Value -= 1;
        }

        protected override void OnIncrement()
        {
            Value += 1;
        }

        protected override void SetValidSpinDirection() { }

        static UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown)));
        }
    }

    public struct Station : IFormattable, IComparable<Station>
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public Station(double value) { Value = value; }

        public int CompareTo(Station other)
        {
            return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        }

        public static Station Parse(string s) { return new Station(double.Parse(s)); }

        public override string ToString() { return Value.ToString(); }
        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            return Value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        }
    }

    public class UpDownBaseStationUpDown : UpDownBase<Station>
    {
        protected override Station ConvertTextToValue(string text)
        {
            return Station.Parse(text);
        }

        protected override string ConvertValueToText()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }

        protected override void OnDecrement()
        {
            Value = new Station(Value.Value - 1);
        }

        protected override void OnIncrement()
        {
            Value = new Station(Value.Value + 1);
        }

        protected override void SetValidSpinDirection() { }

        static UpDownBaseStationUpDown()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UpDownBaseStationUpDown), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UpDownBaseStationUpDown)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Interaction logic for StationUpDownTest.xaml</summary>
    public partial class StationUpDownTest : Window
    {
        public StationUpDownTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Commands
    {
        [CommandMethod("TestMgdStationUpDown")]
        public void TestMgdStationUpDown()
        {
            var dlg = new StationUpDownTest();
            Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.ShowModalWindow(dlg);
        }
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.AutoCAD.UITest"
                    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
                    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <core:VersionResourceDictionary AssemblyName="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" SourcePath="NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="local:UpDownBaseStationUpDown" BasedOn="{StaticResource NumericUpDown}" />

    <Style TargetType="local:UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown" BasedOn="{StaticResource NumericUpDown}" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

StationUpDownTest.xaml:

```
<Window
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.AutoCAD.UITest"
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="My.AutoCAD.UITest.StationUpDownTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <!-- doesn't work -->
        <local:UpDownBaseStationUpDown HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Height="47"
                                       AllowSpin="False"
                                       />

        <!-- works -->
        <local:UpDownBaseDoubleUpDown HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Height="47" 
                                    AllowSpin="False"
                                    />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could it be, because AutoCAD is running in .net Framework v4.0 and Extended WPF Toolkit uses functionality from .net framework v4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), select the acad.exe process and in context menu, **Properties...**, **.NET Assemblies** tab, check which assemblies are loaded. May be there is an older version of **the Extended WPF Toolkit** loaded by another extension.

You can also use [Fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if there is no binding problem.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. One of my colleagues had this idea, too, but the error must be somewhere else. The loaded Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll is the one lying in the BuildOutput directory.

Answer (score 0):

After further days of trying I found out that the error remains even after removing Extended WPF Toolkit.
I also found following Question: [WPF 4.0 Application load error in some environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850185/wpf-4-0-application-load-error-in-some-environments)

My Colleague solved the problem by attaching to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;` and returning `Assembly.LoadFile (assemblyPath);`